# Symfony2 and date_default_timezone_get() - It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: php, symfony, timezone

I have a Symfony2 project. I updated my php to 5.5.7 today and since then, I am getting the

```
Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in...
```

I setup the default timezone in my php.ini

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "Europe/Paris";
```

To be sure that this is the good php.ini, I was checking with

```
phpinfo();
```

And the path I ma getting there is the one I am modifying:

```
 /usr/local/php5.5.7/lib
```

But in there, I see the

```
Default timezone    UTC
```

Which is strange.

any idea? Thank you.

Comment: can you confirm me the full path of the php.ini that you have changed

Comment: if you get this warning in symfony console then you also need to change at cli/php.ini

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to set it in Apache's `php.ini`, but your CLI (Command Line Interface) `php.ini` is not good.

Find your `php.ini` file with the following command:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

And then search for `date.timezone` and set it to `"Europe/Amsterdam"`. all valid timezone will be found here http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Another way (if the other does not work), search for the file `AppKernel.php`, which should be under the folder `app` of your *Symfony* project directory. Overwrite the `__construct` function below in the class `AppKernel`:

```
<?php     

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // Other methods and variables


    // Append this init function below

    public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Paris' );
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but already checked: Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php5.5.7/lib/php.ini

Comment: there should be another configuration for cli, did you check that also?

Comment: Hm, and how to find this second one?

Comment: may I know how you have installed php5.5.7? because normally it should have been placed at etc/php5
anyway you can fix this by set default timezone at karnel class constructor.

Comment: I installed it from source with ./configure  --prefix=/usr/local/php5.5.7

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I know where the problem is. When restarting the php-fpm, I am restarting the old one, do you know how to restart the new php5.5.7 I installed ?

Comment: restarting your apache2 will suppose to restart php as well

Comment: i had the same problem and your another solution works with me

Comment: perfect, saved me lot of time!

Comment: This worked great! It may be valuable to add a link to valid timezone values: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Thanks, I have added

Comment: Hi! in my case i use XAMPP on MacOS, then i do `php -i` and output this:

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc`
`Loaded Configuration File => (none)`

And that's was the problem, in /etc there's no php.ini file, i've created with `sudo nano /etc/php.ini` and add this entry 

    [Date]
    ; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
    ; http://php.net/date.timezone
    date.timezone=Europe/Madrid

and start working, i've tried the @sas solution and work like a charm too.

Comment: I exactly don't where is the bin/php of xampp on mac. please try to find it, should be in the directory of xampp. e.g. run DIR_XAMPP/bin/php -i

Comment: `php --ini` is a nice shortcut

Answer (score 66):

Found a similar way to fix this issue (at least it did for me).

1. First check where the `CLI php.ini` is located:

   `php -i | grep "php.ini"`
2. In my case I ended up with : Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
3. Then `cd ..` all the way back and `cd` into `/etc`, do `ls` in my case php.ini didn't show up, only a php.ini.default
4. Now, copy the php.ini.default file named as php.ini:

   `sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini`
5. In order to edit, change the permissions of the file:

   `sudo chmod ug+w php.ini`

   `sudo chgrp staff php.ini`
6. Open directory and edit the php.ini file:

   `open .`

   *Tip: If you are not able to edit the php.ini due to some permissions issue then copy 'php.ini.default' and paste it on your desktop and rename it to 'php.ini' then open it and edit it following step 7. Then move (copy+paste) it in /etc folder. Issue will be resolved.*
7. Search for [Date] and make sure the following line is in the correct format:

   `date.timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam"`

I hope this could help you out.

Comment: You just saved me a serious headache. Thank you, friend!

Comment: Technically this should be the correct answer as it actually resolves the problem long term.

Answer (score 25):

The current accepted answer by crack is deprecated in Symfony 2.3 and will be removed by 3.0. It should be moved to the constructor:

```
public function __construct($environment, $debug) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
    parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It solved my issue in version 3

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 5.5, there is a separate php.ini file for CLI interface.
If You use symfony console from command line, then this specific php.ini is used.

In Ubuntu 13.10 check file:

> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Answer (score 1):

The problem appear when we are using PHP 5.1 on Redhat or Cent OS

## PHP 5.1 on RHEL/CentOS doesn't support the timezone functions

Answer (score 1):

Following up on [sas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20743237/2877364), PHP 5.4, Symfony 2.8, I had to use

```
ini_set('date.timezone','<whatever timezone string>');
```

instead of `date_default_timezone_set`.  I also added a call to `ini_set` to the top of a custom `web/config.php` to get that check to succeed.

Answer (score -1):

add this code to Your AppKernel Class:

```
public function init()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
    parent::init();
}
```

Comment: `init` is deprecated since version 2.3, to be removed in 3.0. Move your logic in the constructor instead like @Krzysztof Bociurko or the updated accepted answer.