# Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini

Tags: symfony

I have set `date.timezone` in `php.ini` also in `appKernal`.
Also `php app/check.php` giving following message.

> (Your system is ready to run `Symfony2` projects)

But when I access `web/config.php`, it is giving following result:

> Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing:
>   Set the `date.timezone` setting in `php.ini*` (like `Europe/Paris`).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743060/symfony2-and-date-default-timezone-get-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-system/20743237#20743237

Comment: @Zaheer Babar - Have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 13):

If you're a Linux user do these in both files. I had the same issue before and sorted with:

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sudo nano /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

With something like below:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Europe/London
```

EDIT:
Like pointed out comment below there is FPM too so:

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

Comment: As above, command line and web-served PHP will be reading different configs. Location of php.ini file will depend on which type of PHP you're using. For PHP-FPM it's /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

Comment: @AJCerqueti - That's correct! I added it into the answer.

Comment: The list of datetime zones [here](http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.america.php)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me !

in terminal do `sudo vi /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini`
 make sure to change 7.1 to your php version

search for `date.timezone`

change from

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone =
```

to

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```

and restart php... since i am using mac and installed with brew, i restart by the following command `sudo brew services restart php71`

then try again !

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows**

1. You have to edit the `php.ini` file.

-   You can find the `PHP installation path` by opening `CMD`  and typing `where php`

- `php.ini` can be found in the same folder

2. Just open the `php.ini` file in a text editor.
3. search for `date.timezone`

*CHANGE*

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone =
```

*TO*

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```