# Symfony2 config - another data.timezone error

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

I tried to run simple test project but I can not solve data.timezone error. However I have already editet "php.ini" file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmq6V.jpg <-- this is how it looks. 2 ss - error and my current "php.ini" file.

Comment: Did u restart apache?

Comment: Yes, I did restart apache2.

Comment: Screenshots of error messages and configuration files are not really useful or searchable.  Please describe in some detail, what you actually need, and what you've done, and include the _text_ that you think is relevant to your question.

Comment: Did you not see [Set the “date.timezone” setting in php.ini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340066/set-the-date-timezone-setting-in-php-ini/28340185#28340185) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running the Symfony requirements check from the command line and edited the "date.timezone" in your `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file (which is used, if PHP is served via Apache webserver only).

Try editing the "date.timezone" in your `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file as well, because this is the config file, which PHP uses when run via command line.

Answer (score 0):

There was a 2nd php.ini file I could not found. After I have found 1st I thought it is all I have to edit. Both of them were similar.