# Not Found - The requested URL /app/example was not found on this server

Tags: php, symfony, localhost, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have followed the tutorial to get started with Symfony

> https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

and I have first set up a development environment using Vagrant: I created the virtual machine Ubuntu, and it seems that the files in the virtual machine are synchronised with my current Symfony project directory.

When I try to start the server locally from the project folder with the following command:

```
php console server:run
```

or (depending on my current directory)

```
php app/console server:run
```

I get the following error/warning:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>     Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system'
>     s timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or
>      the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those me
>     thods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled th
>     e timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please s
>     et date.timezone to select your timezone.

But apparently this is not a problem, and it is not my actual problem.

I have associated the port `80` of the virtual machine with the port `4567` in my local computer, as explained in the tutorial of Vagrant, by typing the following command in the `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
```

Now, in the [Symfony tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#running-symfony) I am following, to see the initial page, I have to type the following command in the browser URL entry box:

```
http://localhost:8000/app/example
```

But it does not work, because of course I need to use another port, so I try with:

```
 http://localhost:4567/app/example
```

and I get the following page:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was receiving the following error/warning:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>   Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system'
>   s timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or
>   the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those me
>   thods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled th
>   e timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please s
>   et date.timezone to select your timezone

When I run the following command on the terminal:

```
php app/console server:run
```

I decided to try to fix this error/warning, and at the end it started working.

I fixed that warning by following the instructions of the second part of the following answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/20743237/3924118

To the question

[Symfony2 and date_default_timezone_get() - It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743060/symfony2-and-date-default-timezone-get-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-system/20743237#20743237)

But strangely, I need to use the original port `8000`, instead of `4567`:

```
http://localhost:8000/app/example
```