# date.timezone php.ini doesn't set

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony, php-ini

I'm using symfony3 and I want to use phpunit

I'm using MAMP and I created an alias to use its php

my php version is 5.6.10

```
which php
php: aliased to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php
```

with `php --ini` I have this result

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini` 
I set

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Rome"
```

I modified also php.ini from mamp with the same value

when I use phpunit

> 1) Tests\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testIndex
>   date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

In my phpinfo() I have

> Directive Local Value Master Value
>
> date.timezone Europe/Rome Europe/Rome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppKernel you can set default_timezone like this

```
public function boot() {
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
   return parent::boot();
}
```

Comment: I see most answers adding `__construct` instead of `boot`, like http://stackoverflow.com/a/29152788/276648 . Any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Your `phpinfo()` says "Europe/Rome" is set, so I guess you already restarted the webserver?

I always set it with the `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");` function in the top of a PHP file which always get's loaded.

Comment: Yes. I Restarted MAMP (webserver) even I think phpunit uses cli php.
anyway I have the same issue. I don't like use `date_default_timezone_set()` in php file

Comment: **EDIT: sorry didn't see that there aren't any additional conf files**

Check for any additional configuration files, "conf.d" maybe?
I think `phpinfo()` also gives you addition ini file locations which also get loaded

Comment: thanks for your reply. In phpinfo() i can see `Additional .ini files parsed => (none)`

Comment: I checked even in

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf

Loaded Configuration File=> /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini`

And I have `date.timezone = "Europe/Rome"` Everywhere

Comment: Well if you are sure that the php.ini is the only configuration file, then maybe the problem lies within phpunit? Haven't used phpunit in my projects yet. Maybe Barno's solution works if you hook in on the bootstrapping/initialization of phpunit (just a guess)