# How can I set timezone in symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, timezone, symfony3.x

I have a symfony 3 application deployed in Ubuntu 14.04 server.

When I execute ***"date"*** in the command window, the server response me ***"Fri May 11 10:02:30 CEST 2018"*** but when I dump a datetime in twig as ***"{{ dump("now"|date) }}"***, the response is ***"May 11, 2018 04:04"***.

If I put in the header of the controller function (route), ***"date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");"*** it works fine, but I don't want to copy this line in all functions of all controllers.

Then, I want to know where can I set the Timezone as configuration of Symfony or where can I set this PHP command (***date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid")***) globally for all the controllers.

Thank you

**[EDIT]**

One solution may be put this code in the header of the controller, but I want to set it ones, no in all controllers, services, etc...:

```
public function __construct(){
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
}
```

Comment: Why not just set it in php.ini?

Comment: I try it, but it doesnt change in symfony, I don't know why. I try changing the timezone in:
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini,  /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini and /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini and restarting apache but in symfony the datetime not change.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the correct php.ini ? Check out this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743060/symfony2-and-date-default-timezone-get-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-system

Comment: I execute (find / -name "php.ini") and only this files exist in /etc:
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini

I have other ones in vendor directory of symfony:
/var/www/html_back/vendor/doctrine/cache/tests/travis/php.ini
/var/www/html_back/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle/Tests/travis/php.ini
/var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/cache/tests/travis/php.ini
/var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle/Tests/travis/php.ini
/var/www/html/vendor/vendor/doctrine/cache/tests/travis/php.ini

Comment: where is your `php.ini` can you show your route to `php.ini`?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev How can i know wat php.ini is used by system? I have this three: /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.in

Comment: @Argoitzestebanezbarrado The easiest way: from within any controller action just invode `phpinfo()` and `die` afterwards. It should dump a whole set of info - and one of them should be location of php.ini used...

Comment: Thank you @JovanPerovic, I will try it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you can’t set it in `php.ini`, or you want to be sure the value is consistent independently of the target environment, the easiest way is to set it in your AppBundle:

```
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don’t have an AppBundle (or any other own bundle), you could add it to the `AppKernel::registerBundles()` method, right before the bundles are loaded.

Comment: Thanks! In Symfony 4 I solved this issue by adding the mentioned line in `Kernel.php` in the method `registerBundles`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Manager\EventManager;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Extension\CoreExtension;

/**
 * Class TimeZoneListener
 *
 * @package App\EventListener
 */
class TimeZoneSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var Environment */
    private $environment;

    /** @var EventManager */
    private $manager;

    /** @var string */
    private $timezone;

    /**
     * TimeZoneListener constructor.
     *
     * @param Environment  $environment
     * @param EventManager $manager
     * @param string       $timezone
     */
    public function __construct(Environment $environment, EventManager $manager, string $timezone)
    {
        $this->environment = $environment;
        $this->manager     = $manager;
        $this->timezone    = $timezone;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|null
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): ?array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'setTimeZone',
        ];
    }

    public function setTimeZone(FilterControllerEvent $filterControllerEvent)
    {
        if (!$this->environment instanceof Environment) {
            return;
        }

        // decide correct timezone either default or event defined
        $event    = $this->manager->getActiveEvent();
        $timezone = null === $event ? $this->timezone : $event->getTimezone();

        /**
         * set twig default time zone
         *
         * @var CoreExtension $core
         */
        $core = $this->environment->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core');
        $core->setTimezone($timezone);

        return $this->environment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how many times you're going to call this function with this solution?

Comment: Exactly. Whereas if you do it in Boot like the other answer, it's only executed once. Same result, less resource waste.

Comment: Ah, you're probably right. but i'll keep my answer in case where boot isn't a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in app/AppKernel.php if timezone for all your symfony app is defined/

It will overpass the default php conf timezone